# compose and compose/deep for parse rule in red?

Tags: red

How to keep (print text) as it disappears when using compose ?

```
s: {hello test1 parse test2}
t1: "test1"
t2: "test2"

rule: compose [ thru (t1) mark: copy text to (t2) (print text)]
parse s rule
```

same question for compose/deep if it's different answer:

```
s: {hello test1 parse test2. hello second test for test1 parse test2.}
t1: "test1"
t2: "test2"

rule: compose/deep [ any [thru (t1) mark: copy text to (t2) (print text)]]
parse s rule
```

Comment: You aren't limited to what's in the box, so you could make your own COMPOSE-like construct that does other patterns.  For instance, **composeII [1 + 2 (1 + 2) ((1 + 2))]** => **[1 + 2 (1 + 2) 3]**.

Comment: @HostileFork I must not be awaken but I can't see clearly how to do and what you mean :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either convert block to paren, or quote paren:

```
>> compose [something here (to paren! [print text])]
== [something here (print text)]
>> compose [something here (quote (print text))]
== [something here (print text)]
```

It's the same for `compose/deep` .

Answer (score 6):

You aren't limited to what's in the box, so you could make your own COMPOSE-like construct that does other patterns.

For instance, here's a **composeII** which only substitutes for cases where there are nested parentheses.  So it will leave **(x)** alone but evaluate **((x))**.

```
composeII: function [block /only /deep] [
    collect [
        foreach item block [
            case [
                all [
                    paren? :item
                    1 = length? item
                    paren? first item
                ][
                    either only [
                        keep/only do first item
                    ][
                        keep do first item
                    ]
                ]

                all [
                    deep
                    block? :item
                ][
                    either only [
                        keep/only composeII/deep/only item
                    ][
                        keep/only composeII/deep item
                    ]
                ]

                true [
                    keep/only :item
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

So for your case:

```
>> t1: "test1"
>> t2: "test2"

>> composeII/deep [
    any [thru ((t1)) mark: copy text to ((t2)) (print text)]
]

== [
    any [thru "test1" mark: copy text to "test2" (print text)]
]
```

Comment: Please, change `for-each` to `foreach` otherwise it won't work in Red.

Comment: @rebolek It can if you say **for-each: :foreach** to avoid retyping something you wrote in the console (and then forget you did that, so it works on subsequent runs)

Comment: @HostileFork thanks for being so helpfull as usual ;)

Comment: @user310291 Note that the above code--since it is not a "native"--will be significantly slower than COMPOSE.  However, if you were to write it in Red/System, there would be no reason that it would be that much slower.  [Implementation of compose, if you are curious.](https://github.com/red/red/blob/9e5803bb48f6cb39eed40b7af22e4c8853dafd2f/runtime/natives.reds#L1018)

Answer (score 1):

As blocks shield their content from evaluation of **compose** you can also use

```
>> rule: compose [ thru (t1) mark: copy text to (t2) (first [(print text)] )]
== [thru "test1" mark: copy text to "test2" (print text)]
```